# Excel: If either D2 or F2 is 0, leave G2 blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Both D2 and F2 contain formulas that rely on inputted values in other cells. In a third cell (G2), I have a formula that utilizes both D2 and F2. I get accurate results just fine. However, using the formula below, when either D2 or F2 has no value the third cell says "#VALUE!" when I would prefer it to stay blank.

How do I fix that? Neither D2 or F2 are blank because they contain formulas, so I cannot use the ISBLANK condition. And my formula is not fixing it:

```
=IF(OR(D2=0,F2=0),"",IF(F2>D2,F2*2,F2))
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't really return *no value* - if they contain formulas then they return *something*.  Whatever that something is apparently not interpreted as equal to zero, as blanks are.

You could use:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(D2),ISNUMBER(F2)),IF(F2>D2,F2*2,F2),"")
```

Or simply:

```
=IFERROR(IF(F2>D2,F2*2,F2),"")
```

Note that this last will return the value of F2 if F2 is a number but whatever is in D2 is text, since Excel can compare text and numbers, and considers text to be greater.  But, you say that you get an error when *either* has "no value", in which case this will work as expected.

Comment: I meant that D2 and F2 are both formulas but without input from other cells they both appear to be blank. This worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(D2=0,"",IF(E2=0,"",IF(F2>D2,F2*2,F2)))
```